# Conversions are 0 in social analytics

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have an issue with the Social Analytics panel, were the counting of Conversions is always 0.

I recently added the following tracking code to the URLs that I'm sending to Twitter:

```
url?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=mycamp&utm_content=mycont
```

In the Social Analytics panel (Acquisition > Social > Overview), I can correctly see data for "Visits" and "Visits via Social Referral", but "Conversions", "Contributed Social Conversions", "Last Interaction Social Conversions" are all 0.

From other panels, I can see that conversions are properly tracked (e.g. In Conversion > Goals > Overview, or in Acquisition > Campaigns).

I believe that this issue is correlated with my recent change in the URLs. 
Prior to this I was posting URLs like:

```
url?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=mymedium
```

These URLs were NOT tracked as "Visits via Social Referral" within the social panel, still I could see numbers for "Conversions", "Contributed Social Conversions", "Last Interaction Social Conversions", meaning that these numbers were incomplete, but greater than 0.

Any idea?
E.

Comment: In order to be a conversion you must fire a goal or ecommerce event, just attracting traffic from a social network does not count as a conversion unless you create a custom goal to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Sending to twitter.. you anwsered your own question.  Sent like that you are loging to there google analytics.  Im sure someone at twitter has a big question mark in his head right now.

Try looking up eventtracking you want to add it as an onclick in your link to twitter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant is that I send my own tweets with links to my website. I started adding utm codes in the links I post within the tweets. When the user clicks, it arrives on my website and the visit gets tracked by my google analytics.